# How can I stop the whole state of Texas from calling my number?

Tags: iphone, applications, caller-id

I get about 5-6 calls daily (6:30am to 4pm-ish) from the whole state of Texas. My phone number is just one digit away from matching another number with the area code for Texas (which is 936, mine is 939 for PR).

The number leads to this automated system that I can't understand, and it’s asking me immediately for a pin every time I call. I Googled it, and the only thing that comes up is Montgomery County Adult Probation. It’s not spam calling me nor telemarketers, it’s real people, because sometimes I answer and either no one talks or they say: “sorry wrong number.”

What can I do? I’ve had my number for over 10 years, and I don’t want to change it. I know nobody in Texas, so I don’t want anyone calling me from there. Any app around or something? I don’t care if I have to pay a monthly fee.

[image]

Comment: If it's not the same number each time, what exactly are you looking for the software to do?  I don't see any pattern from the numbers in the image you posted.  I only see 2 options, change your number or always be on Do Not Disturb and only allow calls from [numbers already in your contacts](https://www.macworld.com/article/3214636/ios/how-to-block-all-calls-except-those-from-your-contacts.html).

Comment: Your question is confusing even after a little light editing for clarity. Is PR Puerto Rico? When did this start happening?

Comment: See here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277691/can-i-block-entire-area-codes-from-my-iphone?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Ney Gómez, ideally there would be a caller blacklisting app on the AppStore that would allow you to block incoming calls using [regular expressions](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/r/regex.htm), but in my experience nobody has made such an app that actually works. If you do manage to find one, I will gladly help you write a regex string that matches all TX area codes.

Comment: @fsb, the image is cropped. They probably all have TX area codes as the first 3 digits, which I assume is how the iPhone determines that they're from TX.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund Yes, I realize that, but you can't block all numbers from a specific area code (reliably) thru an app.  The phone company might be able to do that so I would also recommend to the OP to check with them.

Comment: Someone suggested [WideProtect Spam Call Blocker](https://itunes.apple.com/app/wideprotect/id1171024059) in an [answer to a different question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/264776/283275) which promises to block incoming calls by the first three digits. If all the unwanted calls have TX area codes and caller ID enabled, this should work.

Comment: [Here's a list of TX area codes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Texas_area_codes)